# how to draw on canvas element in phonegap with touch

Tags: javascript, cordova

i am new at Phonegap, i am working on canvas drawing in Phonegap but canvas element is not responding on touch events i am using Samsung note for testing.Please help me with an example of drawing in canvas element in Phonegap..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Phonegap 2.0.0-based example application on GitHub which demonstrates how to use touch events and canvas to draw: https://github.com/Rockncoder/PGATouchPaint